# How to find the right IP and port when using socket?

Tags: java, sockets

In the Server, I listen a port(8888) when using ServerSocket.Here is the code:

```
private static int porta = 8888;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        System.out.println("Server:Connecting……");
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(porta);
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
```

but my client AndroidPhone never make it to connect the Server.Here is the code:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Socket sen=null;
            try{
                txt.setText("OK!");
                //System.out.println("Client:Connecting……");
                sen = new Socket("192.168.0.106",8888);
                txt.setText("Success!");
```

My IP Address is 192.168.0.106:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbQpm.png)

When I open cmd, enter:   netstat -ano | findstr "8888"
cmd shows like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgqaU.png)

Please HELP me connect the Client and Server.Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the port which is being listened in the Server (My PC).

Comment: Is your Android Phone connected with your network?

Comment: Yes, My PC and my Phone have both connected to the same Wifi.

Comment: I do believe you need to still port forward as `192.168.0.106` is not a routable I.P. address.

Comment: @3kings Then please tell me how to find the right IP Address…I am a student and using educational network supported by my school

Comment: First you should check the IP and subnet mask of your Android Phone `WIFI Settings > Menu > Advanced`

Comment: @郑天宇 Well if your using one by your school i'm sure they wouldn't like you to port forward or stuff like that... Check your firewall settings and make sure java is allowed passed (public & private)

Comment: @Flikk By the way, I am a student and using educational network supported by my school. In my phone,IP:192.168.0.129   subnet mask:255.255.255.0     in my pc,IP:192.168.0.132  subnet mask:255.255.255.0

Comment: @3kings Well I've checked firewall, it didn't work…maybe I should connect to another network?

Comment: @郑天宇 Ok, then both devices are in the same subnet and you should not need any routing with port forwarding. Try to temporarely turn off your firewall. Also trying to execute a ping would help to see if you get a connection at all http://superuser.com/questions/586469/how-to-ping-an-ip-address-from-an-android-device (Android can not get pinged or execute ping without extra software)

Comment: @Flikk I turned off my firewall, and with the help of a ping software, I confirmed that my phone can connect to 192.168.0.132 .But Socket is still not working……

Comment: You should not do this except for testing: Try to change the port in server and client to 21. That's the FTP port. there might be some network settings that block communication over certain ports. If the change to port 21 works, you should try other non standard ports or ask the network administrator which ones you can use.

Comment: `in my pc,IP:192.168.0.132` then what is this IP yuo are trying to connect to `sen = new Socket("192.168.0.106",8888);` ?? **106** ?

Comment: @Yazan Oh I forget to say, my computer gets IP Address automatically.Now IP Address is 192.168.0.132, and I also change the code to "sen = new Socket("192.168.0.132",8888);"

Comment: @郑天宇 have you tried another port (like 21) yet?

Comment: @Flikk Yes I tried.But nothing changes…